# How to start kendo pdf viewer with 'FitToWidth' selected

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to instantiate a pdf viewer to be defaulted to FitToWidth but I cannot find a way to start it out with that option selected,

I tried setting its defaultPageSize settings by setting width with auto but I get the page size to be Automatic Width, is there another value that is set on this property or any other property to initiate the viewer with FitToWidth?

Comment: looking for the same answer, not a lot of docs on this

Comment: @univegar304 I have found a solution

Answer (score 4):

I got help from the Telerik Team and they provided the following answer, I will share it with the community,

it seems that you can set the default zoom scale only on the first render like so

```js
<script>
  var firstRender = true;
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var vr=  $("#pdfViewer").kendoPDFViewer({
            pdfjsProcessing: {
                file: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/web/pdfViewer/sample.pdf"
            },
            width: "100%",
            height: 1200,
            render: function(e) {
              if (firstRender) {
                  e.sender.toolbar.zoom.combobox.value("fitToWidth");
              e.sender.toolbar.zoom.combobox.trigger("change");
                firstRender = false;
              }
            }
        }).getKendoPDFViewer();            
    });
</script>
```

Comment: FYI: This doesn't work on Kendo UI for jQuery R1 2023 because `e.sender.toolbar` doesn't have a `zoom` property,